# Unable to display subview added to WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, wkwebview

I am creating an embedded view for an app using Swift and WKWebView. I am stuck in adding and displaying the UIProgressView (my subview).

Whenever I add it on story builder (on top of the view) and then run the app it does not show because of my code (I associate self.view to the instance of WKWebView that I create).

[image]

I hence tried an **alternative approach** and added it programmatically but won't work either.

Here is my code (for the first approach just ignore the programmatic declaration of UIProgressView):

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class SupportWebView: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var containerView : UIView? = nil
    @IBOutlet var progressView : UIProgressView? = nil

    var webView: WKWebView?

    dynamic var myProgress: Double  = 0
    private var myContext = 0

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.view = self.webView
        self.webView?.navigationDelegate = self
        self.webView?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress", options: .New, context: &myContext)

        let progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .Bar)
        progressView.center = view.center
        progressView.progress = 20.0/30.0
        progressView.trackTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        progressView.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        self.webView?.addSubview(progressView)
//        self.webView.addSubview(progressView)
    }
```

I tried to add the UIProgressView programmatically to the WKWebView view but it won't work.. any suggestion on how to fix this? It seems to display only the main WKWebView and ignore the subviews (they may be rendered before the web view rendering and hence they disappear).

Answer (score 0):

I tested out your code and got it to render the progressView by changing `progressView.center = view.center` to something like `progressView.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 200.0, 5.0)`. I tested without doing anything on the Storyboard.